# Difference between extracting an iso or mounting it

Tags: mount, iso

I'm trying to create a customized Ubuntu installation CD. In the [official documentation of Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization)
it says 
“Copy the CD to your hard drive”
using this command:

```
mount -o loop /path/to/iso /some/mountpoint
```

Is it a problem if I just extract the ISO file?

Comment: "Copy the CD to your hard drive" is that entire section, not just the one command.

Comment: i know i already have an iso on my hard drive i want to know if extracting is diffrent than mounting

Comment: documentation state : `mount ...`  (mounting) then `rsync ...` or `mkdir ... ; cp ...` (extracting) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mounting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_(computing)) a CD image makes the files from that CD image available. The files are still stored on the CD image. Mounting doesn't copy anything, it just makes some files accessible. When the CD image is unmounted, the files will no longer be accessible.

Extracting the CD image (the ISO file) copies the files from the image to some other location. One way to extract the image is to mount it, copy the files from the mount point, and unmount it. The documentation provides instructions for that. If you have a graphical environment that has a menu entry or tool to extract the CD image in one step, you can use that (it probably automates the sequence of operation to mount, copy files and unmount).